# Rails Access data from a different Model within a Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

UPDATE: Problem solved, thanks to Sebastian and Gabriel for the helpful pointers.

The relevant changes to my code are as follows:

**app/controllers/pomodoro_cycles_controller.rb**

```
def pomodoro_collections
  {
    pomodoro_collection_0: Pomodoro.offset(0).first(100),
    pomodoro_collection_1: Pomodoro.offset(100).first(100)
  }
end
```

**app/views/pomodoro_cycles/show.html.erb**

```
<% @pomodoros_collections.each do |pomodoros_collection_hash| %>
  <h2><%= pomodoros_collection_hash[0] %></h2>
  <% pomodoros_collection_hash[1].each do |pomodoro| %>
    <p>
      <%= pomodoro.id %>
      <%= pomodoro.color %>
    </p>
  <% end  %>
<% end  %>
```

**NOTA BENE:**

The `#first` method in ActiveRecord returns an Array, so the keys in my original Hash were nested Arrays.  Instead, the following was sufficient to return an Array of Pomodoro objects:

```
Pomodoro.offset(0).first(100)
```

**DESCRIPTION OF ORIGINAL PROBLEM**

Rails 5, PostgreSQL

**PROBLEM:** I cannot access `Pomodoro.all` from within `PomodoroCycleController`

I have two scaffolds: `Pomodoro` and `PomodoroCycle`, and I want to access the full list of Pomodoros within the PomdoroCycle controller.

The following code is kept simple, in order to make as clear as possible what I'm trying to do.  If I can do these things, then I'll be able to do much more, but one step at a time.

Regarding the db migration files, I have already run `bundle exec rails db:migrate`

I want to display a full list of Pomodoros in the PomodoroCycle Show View (later to be displayed in Index), but I don't know what is missing.

From **app/controllers/pomodoro_cycles_controller.rb**

```
def show
  @pomodoros_collections = pomodoro_collections
end

def pomodoro_collections
  {
    pomodoro_collection_0 => [Pomodoro.offset(0).first(100)],
    pomodoro_collection_1 => [Pomodoro.offset(100).first(100)]
  }
end
```

From **app/views/pomodoro_cycles/show.html.erb**

```
<% @pomodoros_collections.each do |collection| %>
  <p><%= collection %></p>
<% end  %>
```

**However, this displays nothing in the browser.**

**app/models/pomodoro_cycle.rb**

```
class PomodoroCycle < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pomodoros
end
```

**app/models/pomodoro.rb**

```
class Pomodoro < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :pomodoro_cycle
end
```

Updated **db/migrate/20180103032759_create_pomodoro_cycles.rb**:

```
class CreatePomodoroCycles < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :pomodoro_cycles do |t|
      t.string :activity
      t.integer :iteration
      t.integer :matrix_side_length
      t.datetime :created_at
      t.datetime :completed_at
      t.string :category_labels, array:true, default: []
      t.string :category_colors, array:true, default: []
      t.string :username

      t.timestamps
    end

    create table :pomodoros do |t|
      t.belongs_to :pomodoro_cycle, index: true
      t.datetime :completed_at
      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :pomodoros, :pomodoro_cycle_id
  end
end
```

Untouched **db/migrate/20180103054425_create_pomodoros.rb**

```
class CreatePomodoros < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :pomodoros do |t|
      t.boolean :status
      t.string :category
      t.string :color
      t.datetime :completed_at
      t.string :username

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I guess the hash within `pomodoro_collections` doesn't have a valid format, mustn't the keys be strings or symbols?

Comment: @SebastianPalma Ya thats odd, quite surprising it wasn't picked up during the runtime.

Comment: You should put the exact error thrown by rails in the question.

Comment: Thanks @SebastianPalma, what a schoolboy error I made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, as @SebastianPalma pointed out in the comments, the syntax is wrong

```
def pomodoro_collections
 {
  pomodoro_collection_0 => [Pomodoro.offset(0).first(100)],
  pomodoro_collection_1 => [Pomodoro.offset(100).first(100)]
 }
end
```

should be:

```
def pomodoro_collections
  {
    pomodoro_collection_0: [Pomodoro.offset(0).first(100)],
    pomodoro_collection_1: [Pomodoro.offset(100).first(100)]
  }
end
```

Make the keys in the hash `symbols`

Then to display each `Pomodoro` put something like:

```
<% @pomodoros_collections.each do |pomodoros_collection_hash| %>
  <h2><%= pomodoros_collection_hash[0] %></h2>
  <% pomodoros_collection_hash[1].each do |pomodoro| %>
    <p><%= pomodoro.id %></p> #Or the attribute you want to display
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Hope this help